# Why doesn't Google's Multimap's entries() method return Key/Collection pairs?

Tags: java, guava

I would like to be able to retrieve from my `com.google.collections.Multimap<A, B>` a `Collection<Entry<A, Collection<B>>>` which I expected from the `entries()` method, but in fact it returns a `Collection<Entry<A, B>>`.  Is there a method which does what I want?

Currently I'm iterating like this:

```
for (A key: mmap.keySet()) {
    Collection<B> = mmap.get(A);
    //do stuff
}
```

and I'd prefer to be able to iterate like this:

```
for (Entry<A, Collection<B>> entry: mmap.entries()) {
    //do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [asMap()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap%28%29) method:

```
for (Entry<A, Collection<B>> entry: mmap.asMap().entrySet()) {
    //do stuff 
}
```